# Can't import praw in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, import, pip, praw

I've been writing a reddit bot for a while now and recently moved it to a different system. There I've installed the same packages as on the previous system.

The bot is Python3 based so I install `praw`:

```
$ sudo pip3 install praw
[...]
```

Which went just fine as expected, but now when I `import praw`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import praw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .reddit import Reddit  # NOQA
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 11, in <module>
    from prawcore import (Authorizer, DeviceIDAuthorizer, ReadOnlyAuthorizer,
ImportError: No module named 'prawcore'
```

Even after manually adding the path to the module, I can't import `praw`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/')
>>> import praw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .reddit import Reddit  # NOQA
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 11, in <module>
    from prawcore import (Authorizer, DeviceIDAuthorizer, ReadOnlyAuthorizer,
ImportError: No module named 'prawcore'
```

With python(2), it seems to be working just fine.

How can I get my system to successfully import `praw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reddit.com/r/redditdev:

```
pip3 install praw --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

did the job. Apparently something went wrong during the initial installation.